# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'KustoConnectionStringBuilder' could not be found

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer

can someone let me know which nuget package needs to be installed and its corresponding c# reference [using directive] ?
I have installed Kusto.data already

Answer (score 0):

`KustoConnectionStringBuilder` is defined in the `Kusto.Data.dll` assembly, which is distributed as part of the `Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data` package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data/

Comment: using Kusto.Data.Net.Client;
using Kusto.Data;
using System;
namespace LensDashboradOptimization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationClientId="v-vasub";
            var applicationCertificateThumbprint="Vaish4MS*";
            var authority = "microsoft.com";
            var clusterUrl = "https://mycluster.westus.kusto.windows.net";
            var kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(clusterUrl).WithAadApplicationThumbprintAuthentication(applicationClientId, applicationCertificateThumbprint, authority);

Comment: using (var adminProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(kcsb))
  {
                var command = kcsb.ExecuteQuery("StormEvents | count");
                Console.WriteLine(command);
        }
    }
}
    }

Comment: I m getting below error 

Program.cs(23,45): error CS1061: 'ICslAdminProvider' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'ICslAdminProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\v-vasub\Documents\LensDashboradOptimization\LensDashboradOptimization.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Comment: is your project targeting a .NET version which is supported by the library? i.e. .NET Framewoek 4.6.2 or later, or .NET Core 2.0?